# How to insert tweets into a excel file using Azure Logic Apps

Tags: excel, azure, onedrive, azure-logic-apps

I have a Azure logic app that looks up for new tweets with an specific hashtag, but I can't figure out how to insert that tweets into a Excel file. I have seen a Google Sheets option, but I want to do it Excel Online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no out of box excel online connector available as of now. You can always vote for the new features

https://feedback.azure.com/forums/287593-logic-apps/category/145803-connectors